# Totally change url for action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, resources, routes, url-routing, match

I have the following in my routes:

```
  resource :login, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  resources :users, only: [:new, :create] do
    resources :notes
  end
```

but I would like to have url 'my-domain/login' instead of 'my-domain/login/new' and 'my-domain/register' instead of 'my-domain/users/new'.

How can I do than? I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
  match 'login' => 'login#new'
  match 'register' => 'users#new'

  resource :login, only: [:create, :destroy]

  resources :users, only: [:create] do
    resources :notes
  end
```

This gives me error

```
undefined local variable or method `logins_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd99c40c608>:0x007fd99c87bdd8>
```

while visiting 'my-domain/login'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
match '/login',  to: 'login#new'
match '/register',  to: 'users#new'

resource :login, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

A very good tutorial (dare I say "The Best") for learning  Ruby on Rails is [railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). There is a chapter about making a [working login and register page](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-sessions_controller).

**UPDATE**

If you don't want users to visit /users/new I think your current users resources works:

```
resources :users, only: [:create] do
    resources :note
end
```

Since it only matches a route for users/create. You can also redirect users to /register if they go to /users/new. The new action in your Users Controller:

```
def new
  redirect_to register_path
end
```

Comment: This solution doesn't satisfy me because it is still posible for user to visit '/users/new' instead of '/register'

Comment: But it is more complicated because new_user_path still points to '/users/new' but should '/register'

Comment: Are you sure? If you have `resources :users, only: [:create]` there shouldn't be a new_user_path. Try `rake routes` in your console.